# brew update broken, it outputs stashing log

Tags: homebrew, osx-yosemite

Brew update command broken, it out puts stashing log

```
➜  ~  brew update
Stashing your changes:
M README.md
M apple-gcc42.rb
M diffstat.rb
M diffutils.rb
M .............rb
M .............rb
```

Comment: Does it fail or does it succeed? Does it print any additional messages?

Comment: it succeeds, it actually prints those stashing changes, then down it updates like it used to do.. or already updated.., i don't the log changes to be printed on the terminal..

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't intentionally make changes to those files, you can reset them to Homebrew's version with `cd $(brew --repository) && git reset --hard origin/master`.

Comment: still does the same thing, please have a look at the screen shot here http://pasteboard.co/2b8qUxaq.png